# Sparrow for iPhone: Download all mails

Tags: applications, email

I use Sparrow for iPhone with Gmail.

Sometimes it confuses me because the unread count for some of my labels doesn't match with the one shown in the Google Mail app (it's lower, presumably because Sparrow doesn't download all mails).

The thing is, that I know the expected unread counts of most labels, and if they differ from the official app, I can't quickly see whether there is something new in or not.

I think for this to work correctly, Sparrow would have to download all mails, or update the unread mail counts from the server instead of the mails it already has on the device.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 2):

Sparrow computes the number of unread emails based on the downloaded emails in the specific folder.
That would be possible to show the number of emails based on the server but some servers shows the wrong information, some servers requires to consume lots of bandwidth to get that information.

Comment: That's what I thought. Though not a good fit with my workflow. Should probably file a bug report.

Comment: @Timm Well, since Dinh Viêt Hoà is one of the Sparrow devs, it doesn't seems like they're going to address it.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know this was a canonical answer then. @Dinh, is this a problem specifically with `Google Mail` then? Or would it be possible to improve the situation for GMail users, while other people with different providers don't have up to date read counts?

Answer (score -1):

No need to waste all your bandwidth on downloading all mails. According to the [Sparrow website](http://sparrowmailapp.com/iphone.php), there is one button where you can select all your mails as read...

[image]

Comment: I don't want to mark any mails as read. I just want to have the unread count in sync for all labels, so I can easily view them. For example in `amazon` I have two unread mails containing gift cards. I will only look in there if the unread count is 3 or more. Or maybe my workflow doesn't fit on the Google Mail model?

Comment: Please describe your workflow in your original answer

Comment: Done, sorry if my original question led into the wrong direction.